# Export Access query to text without delimiter

Tags: ms-access-2016

I need you support.
I need to export on MS Access Query to TXT but without field delimiter. Is there a way by using VBA or SQL?

**The output I'm getting is:**
aaaaa bbbbb ccccc

**The output I need is:**
aaaaabbbbbccccc

I tried to look here for topics that could enlighten me but I could not find the proper one that could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement.

Anyway, you could simply concatenate the values and export as single string field.

```
SELECT Field1 & Field2 & Field3 AS TheOutput 
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andre

I know that is strange but I need to import a txt file into another software that manage a database and the format of the information must be in txt format without field delimiter.
I also thought to make a new query to combine all fields into a single one but I wanted to avoid to create a new query. I thought that it could exist a simple procedure to reach the desired output.